# tinyMCE Editor button text length too long, How can i word-wrap it?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE editor. The button text in the toolbar is lengthy. How can i break that into lines so that it appears good.
[TinyMCE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDcID.jpg)

The buttons in this tool bar are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the css of the tinymce toolbar -in this case button width- using the tinymce init configuration paramter `editor_css`. Check [this link](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/) for examples.